Using "and" in the search field always does a regular search instead of a tag search
Background on searching
There are two search types one can perform:

Tag search

Only returns questions when searching for tags, like [tag-a] [tag-b] which gives results of questions that have both tags on them.
The URL of the page you get after searching is /questions/tagged/<query> for example searching for [bug] [search] leads to https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/bug+search


Regular search:

Returns questions and answers and involves searching for text. If any tags are present, they are also taken into account - the result would contain questions with the tag and answers to questions with these tags, as long as they also contain the text that was searched for.
The URL of the page you get after searching is /search?q=unicorn+[search] for example searching for unicorn [search] leads to https://meta.stackexchange.com/search?q=unicorn+[search]



The tag search also supports keywords:

or will return questions with either tag mentioned. For example [bug] or [search] results in https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/bug+or+search
and will return questions with both tags. Identical to omitting the word but it is a supported operator. See a manually constructed URL for [bug] and [search] https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/bug+and+search which searches for both tags

The problem
Trying to put in tags with the and operator in the search box will perform regular search. So [bug] and [search] actually goes to /search?q=[bug]+and+[search] which searches for questions and answers where the question has both tags bug search and the post contains the text "and". Therefore the result is drastically different from a tag search using the same terms.
Additional observations
This did not use to be the case. I do not know when and stopped being respected as a tag search term.
The or does work - putting it in a tag query still performs tag search.
Using and in a custom filter does still do a tag search (although, that is inevitable, since all custom filters are based on tag searches).

So I was going to say that I didn't quite follow, since it seemed to me like "and" was just being ignored in the forced tag search because it's not a real tag, but other non-tag values do get turned into tags, so some sort of special handling definitely seems to be taking place there: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/bug+and+these+arent+real+either

So it's not just that it does a regular search, but also that it includes "and" as a word to search for

@M.Justin yep, that's what a regular search does - takes all non-tag (surrounded in square brackets) terms and searches for them as content. A tag search would use the "and" operator as an intersection
